# Elasticsearch Highlight

Tags: elasticsearch, highlight

I have a Elasticsearch 2.4.0 installation. Now I would like to use highlight information. With the following query I get a result list with some hits, but no highlights. Any idea?
Regards CL

```
{
  "query": {
  "query_string" : {
    "query":      "harley" 
  }
}, 
    "highlight" : {
        "pre_tags" : ["<tag1>"],
        "post_tags" : ["</tag1>"],
        "fields" : {
            "GivenName" : {},
            "FamilyName" : {}
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to tell elastic what field should highlighting be run on. When using query in this way you use implicit _all fields. Probably highlight needs explicit fields? Found in docs: "The _all field cannot be extracted from _source, so it can only be used for highlighting if it mapped to have store set to true." https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I think I specified the fields (GivenName, FamilyName).

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry. Maybe you get hits that match on other fields. Do you get any highlights when adding `"fields" : ["GivenName", "FamilyName"],` to query_string?

Comment: As says @slawek, you need to add the `fields` field in your query property like:

`"query_string" : {
    "fields": ["GivenName", "FamilyName"],
    "query":      "harley" 
  }`